# The difference between datetime data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i find the difference between two dateTime store in a MySQL database
e.g the difference in hours between 2016-03-09 04:30:00 and 2016-03-10 03:00:00.
i have tried dateDiff() but it does not compare the hours that is need to see the difference between (2016-03-09 04:30:00) - (2016-03-10 03:10:00).
the order is year-month-day time

[image: Structure of database]

The output i need is the number of hours between these times also considering the time as well.

Comment: What value are you looking for?

Comment: The number of hours in between the two date time @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to find the difference between two timestamps

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2009-05-18 10:00','2009-05-18 11:00');
```

If you want fraction(eg: 1.5 hrs) hours you can do like below

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-30 10:40')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-30 10:30'))/3600 hour_diff
```

Comment: I need the difference between time as well not only the dates

Comment: Updated my answer , please check

Comment: Thanks @timus2001 that is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to use `to_seconds()`:

```
select to_seconds(dt1) - to_seconds(dt2)
```

This gives the difference in seconds.  Then you can divide by 60*60 to get hours or 24*60*60 for days.

Comment: That compares the dates only not the time @GordonLinoff

Comment: @johnnitro . . . I'm not sure what you mean by that.  It is the number of seconds between the two values (or hours or days), including the time component.